# How can I stop an If statement from running

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

```
private function BatCondition():void 
    {

        //updateScoreText();
            if (nScore == 10)
            {
                trace('run once')


            }
    }
```

okay. so you see when the score is 10. it keeps tracing one once, x amount of times when i want it to run once, help.

p.s break does not work. C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\update2\src\Main.as(337): col: 22 Error: Target of break statement was not found.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way how break out of an **if** statement.

```
mainIf: if (some_condition)
{
   trace("Main condition")   

   innerIf: if (your_condition)
   {
      trace("inner if");
      break mainIf;

   }
   trace("this won't work")
}
```

If you want to break out of an **if** statement or a loop use the `break` keyword. If you have multiple if's and or loops you can add labels to them to target the if/loop you want to break out of.

Comment: This really should be the "correct" answer.  +1 for directly answering the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

private function BatCondition():void 
    {

```
    //updateScoreText();
        if (nScore == 10)
        {
            trace('run once')
            break;


        }
}
```

Comment: p.s break does not work. C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\update2\src\Main.as(337): col: 22 Error: Target of break statement was not found.

Comment: :O try removing semicollen. or try continue insted or use goto

Comment: same error.
And another thing is that i'm using flash develop, so i don't know how i can use goto on here :/ than you tho

Comment: u can write nScore++; but this is temporary solution

Comment: write break after bracket means outside of if loop.

Answer (score 1):

How about a class level var to act as a flag.

eg,

```
private var score_at_ten_flag:Boolean = false;

private function BatCondition():void {
     if (nScore == 10 && !score_at_ten_flag) {
          score_at_ten_flag = true;
          trace('run once');
     }
}
```